# How to automatically adjust the levels of a grayscale

Tags: texturing, compositing-nodes

I want to generate a greyscale to apply a color ramp on it to generate my texture. In order to get the most value depth on this greyscale i want to adjust the levels in the compositor so the darkest color gets a value of 0 and the brightest color has a value of 1. I want Blender to detect the values automatically like the Auto Level node of Substance Designer.

Here is an image i have created for the test with bad levels:

[image]

And the result I want to generate in the compositor with automatic detection:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure just grab a Normalise node from the Vector node category.

[image: Normalise node]

And you can apply this to colour images by separating out the value component.
In this example I have intentionally underexposed the source using a colour curve node. You can compare the results in the split viewer node.

[image: Normalize color image]

A useful application would be to smooth out exposure of time-lapse recordings. Where lighting conditions and therefore exposure, change radical during a recording.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Also i add that if the greyscale must be exported a Gamma node with a value of 2.2 must be added to export it as Linear color space.

Comment: When I applied the normalize node to an image with baked in gamma it did not seem to shift the gamma value. But if you try to balance very underexposed images with baked in gamma you will notice a shift as the original mid point zooms up to the top value.